# How to use and S3 bucket for a website on K3S

Tags: apache, kubernetes, amazon-s3, k3s

I have a k3s cluster.  I am trying to deploy an apache web server that has some legacy html sites.  The web server's html files are on an S3 bucket hosted by Wasabi.  I have tried to use [datashim](https://github.com/datashim-io/datashim) without any luck.  Could someone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?  Not sure if this is a compatibility issue with K3S or if I am just doing this completely wrong.  When I exec into the pod I see the /mnt/dataset directory, but it does not mount the S3Bucket, I just get the following files "bucket, endpoint, folder, region"

```
---
kind: Dataset
apiVersion: datashim.io/v1alpha1
metadata:
  name: wasabi-dataset
spec:
  local:
    type: "COS"
    accessKeyID: "$(kubectl get secret wassabi-s3 -o=jsonpath='{.data.access-key}' | base64 --decode)"
    secretAccessKey: "$(kubectl get secret wassabi-s3 -o=jsonpath='{.data.secret-key}' | base64 --decode)"
    endpoint: "https://s3.wasabisys.com"
    bucket: "s3-storage"
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: apache-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: apache
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: apache
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: apache
        image: php:apache
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: "/mnt/dataset"
            name: "wasabi-dataset"
      volumes:
        - name: "wasabi-dataset"
          configMap:
            name: "wasabi-dataset"
```